# How to what program each logged in user is executing in linux?

Tags: linux

What command line would give me a list of programs each logged in user is executing for a Linux server using bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`w`](http://www.linuxnix.com/4-linux-w-command-examples/) command for this.

As @ivanivan mentioned, a more complete listing can be accomplished using [`ps`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps), usually coupled with `grep` to filter out what you don't want.

Comment: This doesn't show much - with firefox, chrome, pidgin and a terminal running it only reports that I'm running a mate-session the w command.  Using ps with some options - like  ps auwx -  will give you a much better idea...